# Can you use formatted strings to find elements by whatever category (xpath, css, etc) in selenium for Python?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I just realized this and it's kind of scary because my program revolves around finding elements by CSS selector using formatted strings.

Take this for example:

```
stop_iteration_for_foh = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'.subheader-row:nth-child({the_counter}) .subheader-title-container')
```

Just a simple counter in a for loop that gets incremented by 1 each time and I get this error...

```
line 81, in actually_create_schedule
    stop_iteration_for_foh = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'.subheader-row:nth-child({the_counter}) .subheader-title-container')

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".subheader-row:nth-child(3) .subheader-title-container"}
```

I'm now wondering if selenium accepts this, because of the way the "line 81 in..." error is shown. Any help?

Comment: I see this in error stack trace `.subheader-row:nth-child(3) .subheader-title-container` it has 3 in numeric format. What is the initial value of `the_counter` ?

Comment: Hello @cruisepandey, the counter does indeed start off at 3. I didn't realize that and it basically answers the question of whether formatted strings work with selectors. Now I wonder what it could possibly be!

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
subheader-row:nth-child({the_counter})
```

with inital value as `3`

and in errorStackTrace it is getting replaced like this :

```
.subheader-row:nth-child(3)
```

Basically you can pass any counter value in xpath or css, the more important thing is that it should be a valid locator.

> Go to Chrome - > Dev too (F12) and then Elements section and then do
> CTRL + F and then paste `.subheader-row:nth-child(3) .subheader-title-container` to see if there's any highlighted entry,
> if there is then you should be good to go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can pass parameters to your locators.
For example your locator is `.subheader-row:nth-child({the_counter}) .subheader-title-container` so you can do something like this:

```
element_locator = '.subheader-row:nth-child({0}) .subheader-title-container'
for i in range (1,10):
    element_locator.format(i)
    stop_iteration_for_foh = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element_locator)
```

Comment: great answer as always. Sometimes I wonder when you sleep :)

Comment: Normally I sleep somewhere between 1 to 8 in the morning middle east time zone 